# how to query some characters in one field?

Tags: sql, string, oracle

My database is Oracle 11g.

I want to do a in query in sql. The query criteria is to matched some of the characters of a field:

```
    description
    CWLV321900017391;EFHU3832239
    CWLV321900017491;ERHU3832239
    CWLV321900017591;ERHU3832239
    CWLV321900017691;ERHU3832239
```

My query is like this:

```sql
select * from product where description in ('CWLV321900017391', 'CWLV321900017491');
```

It returns no records in result.

I expect the result like below:

```
    description
    CWLV321900017391;EFHU3832239
    CWLV321900017491;ERHU3832239
```

How to get it by SQL?

thanks.

Comment: A table has _columns_, not fields. And _rows_, not records.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a single column. That is a really bad idea to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `IN` to search for a partial string match in the `description` table.  This is not going to return the results, as `IN` will only match exact values.

Instead, one way to achieve this is to use a `LIKE` operator with `%`:

```
select  *
  from  product
  where (description LIKE 'CWLV321900017391%' OR
        description LIKE 'CWLV321900017491%');
```

The `%` at the end indicates that *anything* can follow after the specified text.

This will return any `description` that *starts with* `CWLV321900017391` or `CWLV321900017491`.

Incidentally, if your search term occurs *anywhere* in the description field, you will need to use a `%` at each end of the search term:

```
description LIKE '%CWLV321900017391%' OR description LIKE '%CWLV321900017491%'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to solve it. Here is one:

```
select * from product 
where instr (description, 'CWLV321900017391') > 0
or    instr (description, 'CWLV321900017491') > 0;
```

If you know you're always searching for the start of the `description` you can use:

```
select * from product 
where substr (description, 1, 16) in ('CWLV321900017391','CWLV321900017491')
```

Also, there's LIKE or REGEX_LIKE solution. It depends really on what strings you're searching for.

---

Of course none of these solutions is truly satisfactory, and for large volumes of data may exhibit suck-y performance. The problem is the starting data model violates [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) by storing non-atomic values. Poor data models engender clunky SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way -

```
select * from product 
where substr(description,1,instr(description,';',1,1)-1) in ('CWLV321900017391', 'CWLV321900017491')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am opposed to storing multiple values in a delimited string format.  There are many better alternatives, but let me assume that you don't have a choice on the data model.

If you are stuck with strings in this format, you should take the delimiters into account.  You can do this using `like`:

```
where ';' || description || ';' like '%;CWLV321900017391;%'
```

You can also do something similar with `regexp_like()` if you want to look for one of several values:

```
where regexp_like(';' || description || ';',
                  '(;CWLV321900017391;)|(;CWLV321900017391;)'
                 )
```